# On the general linear group of a vector space of infinite dimension

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $F/\mathbb Q$ be a finite normal extension of the rational numbers. Let $V$ be an $F$-vector space of countably infinite dimension, and set $L=GL_F(V)$. Put moreover $L^*$ be the set of all mappings fixing elementwise at least one subspace of finite codimension in $V$.

1) Is $U=L' L^*/L^*$ simple modulo its center? What is the center? I heard in a conference that this is the multiplicative group of $F$, but is there any way to easily see it? My guess is that $U$ is an union of special linear groups, but also then why the center is such?

2) How does $H = \mathrm{Gal}(F/\mathbb Q)$ act on $Z(U)$?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the quantification in your definition of $L^*$.  Is it correct that you choose a fixed subspace $V'$ of $V$ of finite $F$-codimension and put $L^* = \{T \in L : T(V') \subseteq V'\}$?

Comment: (Also, is $L'$ the derived subgroup of $L$?)

Comment: No, we do not fix it. $L^*$ is made by the mapping fixing a random (but at least one) a subspace of finite codimension. Yes $L'$ is the derived subgroup.

Comment: And 'fixes' means 'fixes pointwise' (rather than just 'stabilises')?

Comment: The question is badly formulated. $L^*$ is a set, a group or a semigroup? Of what kind of mappings: linear? Is $L^*$ a subgroup of $L$? If not, what does $L'L^*/L^*$ mean?

Comment: @MarkSapir $L^*$ is the subgroup made of all elements of $L$ fixing elementwise at least one subspace of finite codimension in $V$.

Comment: I think it's known that $L'=L$ in this case. Actually, $L^*$ is not normal in $L'L^*=L$, so $U$ is ill-defined as a group.

Comment: @YCor I think $U$ is normal in $L$, since if an element $v$ of $L^*$ fixes, say, the subspace $W$, then a conjugate $v^w$ by an element of $w\in L$ will fix $W^{w}$, which still is of finite codimension.

Comment: Oh, now the definition of $L^*$ is finally clear (since your last edit). So I agree that $L^*$ is normal.

Comment: I maintain that $L'=L$, so the question is about the structure of $L/L^*$. Indeed it admits $F^\times$ as a central subgroup, namely those elements acting as a scalar multiplication on some subspace of finite codimension. It's indeed reasonable to expect the quotient to be simple.

Comment: Anticipating that the canonical injective homomorphism $F^\times\to Z(L/L^*)$ is an isomorphism, the action of the Galois group is the canonical one one $F^*$, so Question 2 is trivial. It remains to show that $L/L^*F^\times$ is simple, which sounds likely and probably exists in the literature.

Comment: I found the reference. That $L$ is perfect and that $L/L^*F^\times$ is simple were proved in the paper: MR: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=102528 JSTOR: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970248?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents (Rosenberg, Alex
The structure of the infinite general linear group. 
Ann. of Math. (2) 68 1958 278-294.) Sorry, these links are behind a paywall.

Comment: @YCor Ok, I think your comments answered all my doubts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything can be answered relying on the paper *Rosenberg, Alex
The structure of the infinite general linear group. 
Ann. of Math. (2) 68 1958 278-294* ([MR link](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=102528), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970248); sorry these are under paywalls.)

Namely, $L$ is perfect, and every proper normal subgroup of $L$ is contained in $L^*F^\times$. In particular, $U=L/L^+F^\times$ is a simple group. In particular, $F^\times L^*/L^*\simeq F^\times$ is equal to the center of $L^*$.

The action of the Galois group on $F^\times$ is the natural one, and hence this is the same when viewing $F^\times$ as center of $L/L^*$.